# Create a Make Table from Ms Access Into Sql-Server

Tags: ms-access

I work at a firm that is starting to utilize a hybrid data management system (Ms Access front end, Sql-Server backend). We have many many many people who are proficient in Access (as access suffices about 90% of our needs) but we starting to run into size issues. As we make the migration, I'd love to use as little T-SQL Code as possible to allow people to continue with their current workflows. For the few projects that have Sql-Server, I've used SSMA to push tables from access to SQL Server but I am looking for a more efficient way to do this. Ultimately I'd love to copy the efficacy of an MS Access make table query. I'd rather not use the time consuming method of:

```
Create Table Location_Sql_Test (
Column 1 varchar(50)
Column 2 varchar(50)
etc.
etc.)
```

Is there a way to do something like the below? Do note that Location_Sql_Test doesn't exist yet in my Sql-Server database.

```
SELECT *
INTO
    [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER="myserver";DATABASE="myproject";Trusted_Connection=yes].Location_SQL_TEST
FROM Location_SQL;
```

Literally, can I create a table in Sql-Server from MS Access without needing to open SSMA or SSMS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
SELECT * INTO
[ODBC;DRIVER=SQL 
Server;SERVER="myserver";DATABASE="myproject";
Trusted_Connection=yes].Location_SQL_TEST
FROM Location_SQL;
```

So:

```
SELECT * INTO
[ODBC;DRIVER=SQL 
Server;SERVER="myserver";DATABASE="myproject";
Trusted_Connection=yes].MySQLServerNewTableName
FROM MyLocalAccessTable;
```

Comment: how is that different from what I have? The error is still that Location_SQL_TEST doesn't exist.

Comment: it should work. As long as your connection string is correct then what I have works for me. And looking at your example? The table part was cut off - I did not scroll to the right - but now that I have? Yes, it should work just fine. hit ctrl-g, and in debug windows type in ? currentdb.TableDefs("a linked table to sql server").Connect    (look at the connection string - try what this spits out). After you do this, check on sql server - the table will and should have been created.